# Прибавить к дате часы и минуты

Tags: дата, время, php

```
//Есть два массива, первый дата и время начала занятий, второй продолжительность. Нужно посчитать во сколько и какого числа закончатся занятие. Но, чтобы $call_date и $call_length остались со старыми значениями.
$call_date = array (date_create('2016-01-01 0:45'), date_create('2016-01-01 0:30'), date_create('2013-01-01 0:30'), date_create('2015-01-01 0:30'), date_create('2014-01-01 0:30'));
$call_length = array (date_create('10:40'), date_create('15:45'), date_create('11:00'), date_create('15:45'), date_create('11:00'));

$calls_count = count($call_date);

// Создаем новый массив с временем окончания интервью, так условия получаются менее громоздкими
$call_end = $call_date;

for ($i = 0; $i<=$calls_count - 1; $i++)
{
date_add($call_end[$i], new DateInterval("P0Y0M0DT" . date_format($call_length[$i], 'H') . "H" . date_format($call_length[$i], 'i') . "M"));
};

// Хоть $call_end посчитал правильно, но $call_date изменилось.
// Выводим исходные данные на экран и видим что новые данные в массиве $call_end и $call_date, хотя $call_date должен был остаться не изменным.
foreach ($call_date as $c_d)
{
echo " "; echo date_format($c_d, 'd.m.Y H:i'); echo '<br />';
};
```

Почему такое происходит, и как правильно это решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант клонировать каждый элемент массива:

```
// Тут ваша инициализация

// Создаем новый массив, я изменил на пустой, дальше будем заполнять его
$call_end = array ();

for ($i = 0; $i<=$calls_count - 1; $i++)
{
    $d1 = clone $call_date[$i];
    $call_end[] = date_add($d1, new DateInterval("P0Y0M0DT" . date_format($call_length[$i], 'H') . "H" . date_format($call_length[$i], 'i') . "M"));
};

// Выводим исходные данные на экран
foreach ($call_date as $c_d)
{
echo " "; echo date_format($c_d, 'd.m.Y H:i'); echo '<br />';
};
```